# Netbeans 9.0 Incubating - Does not make `lib` directory in `dist` for migrated/updated Java 10 project

Tags: ant, java-10, netbeans-9

I have started using NetBeans 9.0 (incubating) with Java 10. I created a new test Java Application project and ticked 'Use Dedicated Folder for Storing Libraries' ('\lib') when creating it. I also set the JDK/Java version to `10`. I then included Apache Commons Codec 1.11 as a dependency library. I didn't do anything else, other than import the `Base64` class from the `binary` package in the main class.

However, when I build the application, NetBeans doesn't create a `lib` directory in the `dist` directory, nor does it create a fat Jar that includes the `org.apache.commons.codec.*` package(s) from the library.

This seems specific to Java 10, because it behaved as expected (copied libraries across) when I changed the JDK/Java version to 8.

**Edit:** I have seen various answers to other questions (about other versions of Netbeans and Java) that put forth various `target` and `condition` fragments to place in the build scripts to override `build-impl.xml`, which I have tried to no effect.

This leaves two questions?

1. Does Netbeans 9.0 not fully support Java 10, causing the copyLibs task to fail silently?
2. Does Java 10 not support creating a `lib` directory relative to the application jar or am I failing to configure the project correctly?

*Note:* The purpose of the test project was to diagnose if I could reproduce an issue affecting a larger project that needs to be updated to use a newer version of Java. The old project uses a number of libraries developed internally by the company for which I work. We do not have the resources necessary to set up and migrate to a Maven-based build system and are still using Ant.

Comment: You are quoting the _'Separate Libs Directory'_ as though there is a field somewhere within NetBeans with that name, but I don't see it anywhere. Are you referring to the _'Use Dedicated Folder for Storing Libraries'_ field in the wizard for creating a Java Application, or something else entirely?

Comment: @skomisa Yes, that was what I meant. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem.

Unfortunately this is a NetBeans 9.0 bug. See [NETBEANS-1097 "Copy Dependent Libraries" does not work if "Source/Binary Format" is JDK 9 or JDK 10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1097?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20text%20~%20dist).

That bug describes a possible workaround which is also mentioned in Halvor's answer. However, although that does not appear to work for you (based on your comment), it partially worked for me:

- Edit **nbproject/build-impl.xml** as detailed in the bug.
- Clean and build the project.
- After doing that **commons-codec-1.11.jar** is placed in directory **dist/lib**.
- However, I still did not get the fat jar.

One other thing I tried was **{project } > right click  > Properties > Libraries**, then editing the **Libraries Folder** field, changing it from a relative path to an absolute path. That did not seem to make things better or worse.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, *not* because I implemented the solution (a hack/workaround that gets removed by Netbeans on regenerating `build-impl.xml`), but because it's a reproducible bug that has been reported to Apache and isn't anything I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround for this problem appears to be modifying your `build-impl.xml`.

Find the following condition:

```
<condition property="do.mkdist">
    <and>
        <isset property="do.archive"/>
        <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
        <not>
            <istrue value="${mkdist.disabled}"/>
        </not>
        <not>
            <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
        </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

And remove the segment regarding `modules.supported.internal`, leaving you with:

```
<condition property="do.mkdist">
    <and>
        <isset property="do.archive"/>
        <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
        <not>
            <istrue value="${mkdist.disabled}"/>
        </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

Unfortunately NetBeans will overwrite this change at times, but it should still function as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief I'm fairly sure the above step has to be done for it to function. However, could you try this in addition: Find and place `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` in your project root (next to `build.xml`). Then add this line to the end of your `nbproject/project.properties` file: `libs.CopyLibs.classpath=org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar`