# NetBeans 10: missing external libraries in dist/lib

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-10

I used to work with NetBeans 8 and when I used to "clean and build" my project, NetBeans used to put `MyProject.jar` in the directory `dist/`, and ALL the external libraries and projects in `dist/lib/`.

But recently, I've installed NetBeans 10 and after a "clean and build" only the file `MyProject.jar` is in `dist/`. I've found many discussions/blogs/etc. online to create a single jar file with all the external librairies inside, but it's not what I need.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 9.0 Incubating - Does not make \`lib\` directory in \`dist\` for migrated/updated Java 10 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408574/netbeans-9-0-incubating-does-not-make-lib-directory-in-dist-for-migrated-u)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the file `nbproject/build-impl.xml` was really different. Hopefully, I still had this file from my former NetBeans 8 version and I replaced the new file by the old one and it works.

If someone has a better solution/explanation, I still take it.